# CSS Button - Vertically centre text

Tags: css, cross-browser

I have a Button that is a simple anchor tag styled with the following -

```
.buyBtn{ 
   background:url(../images/buyBtn.png) no-repeat; 
   padding-top:4px; 
   width:97px;     
   height:28px; 
   margin-top:14px;
}
.buyBtn a{
   color:#fff!important; 
   font-weight:normal!important; 
   text-decoration:none;
   padding-left:27px;  
   padding-top:12px; 
   text-shadow:none!important;
}
```

I'm having problems vertically centering the text within the button, it appears fine in some devices, but off centre in others.

Can anybody recommend a way to fix this or a better solution to achieve the same result?

Cheers

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**HTML:**

```
<div class="buyBtn"><a href="#">Button</a></div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.buyBtn{ 
    background:url(../images/buyBtn.png) no-repeat; 
    width:97px;     
    height:28px; 
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.buyBtn a{
    color:#fff!important; 
    font-weight:normal!important; 
    text-decoration:none;
    padding-left:27px;
    text-shadow:none!important;
}
```

No need to use `padding-top` or `margin-top` for vertical align. Just use `display: table-cell;` and `vertical-align: middle;`. Thats it.

Comment: you can't add margin to position a table-cell element so this application of this technique is limited if you need to position the .buyBtn using margin.

Comment: Way to complex, just use the line-height as stated above.

Comment: You shouldn't use display: table-cell on a non-table element.

Answer (score 39):

Use line-height to center it vertically. I usually use the same value as its height.

Comment: should be an accepted answer IMO. Crystal clear, no hacks

Comment: Works only when you know the height.

Comment: I set `height` to `0` and `line-height` to zero and this worked!

Comment: I have used `height: <some_value>` and then set `line-height:0` and it has worked.

Comment: I believe this only works if there is only one line of text - correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Use line-height where and with what value?

Answer (score 11):

Flexbox helped me nail it. Assume you have an excel button (an anchor tag, really).

**HTML**

```
<a class="btn-excel" href="/Export/ExportListToExcel">
    Export To Excel
</a>
```

**CSS**

```
.btn-excel {
    background-color: #32CD32; /*lime green*/
    color: #fff;
    outline: none;
    border-radius: 0.3rem;
    text-decoration: none;
    width: 5rem;
    height: 2.5rem;
    /* Flex rules 'em all */
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
.btn-excel:hover {
    background-color: #808000; /*olive*/
    cursor: pointer;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Comment: You can use display: inline-flex if you'd prefer buttons to sit side-by-side.

Answer (score 1):

I would use `line-height` as bchhun as mentioned. Also, `padding-top` & `padding-bottom` can help.

Answer (score 1):

You can copy this code and put it as a CSS and adjust the things as you need

```
.btn-alignment{
    width: 88px;
    height: 40px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
    display: inline-block;
    line-height: 40px;
    margin-top: 9px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try setting a font-size to your link ? Each browser probably has its own default size, so that may be an hint. Be careful too with padding and width/height, you need to decrease the block size if you add padding 'cause the padding is included in the width. For example, a simple block of 100px width without padding will have a size of 100px : ok. Add a `padding-left: 10px;` and your block now has a width of 110px. ;)